# I want to make universal method in CLASS for all enums

Tags: java, excel, enums

```
public class TableContent {
public static String EXCEL_SHEET_NAME = Nit.THEAD.getName();
public static String FILENAME= Nit.FILENAME.getName();
    public enum Nit {
        FILENAME("Nit-workorder-list"),
        THEAD("NIT WORKORDER"),
        TENDERSPECNO("TENDER SPECFICATION NO."), 
        FEE("TENDER FEE"), 
        SDAMOUNT("SD AMOUNT"), 
        TYPE("NIT TYPE"), 
        PRE_BID("PRE BIDDING DATE"), 
        OPEN_DATE("OPENING DATE"), 
        STATUS("CONTRACTOR STATUS");

        private final String name;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        private Nit(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public static Nit getNitHeadByName(String name)
        {
            Nit[] nit=Nit.values();
            if(nit==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            for(Nit nitHead:nit)
            {
                if(nitHead.getName().equals(name))
                    return nitHead;
            }
            return null;
        }


        public enum NitWorkOrder {
      }
       public enum NitList {
      }
```

My objective is:
I want to export excel sheet from my application, every time I need to hardcode the table headings, which was not good programming practice.

So I use `enum` to overcome the hardcode problem. Now there are different table heading according to the list, then I enclosed all the required ENUMS in single class.

I used to write  `getXXXByName()` and `getXXXByValue()` to access the enum, by name or by value.

But he problem is I need to write `getXXXByName()` and `getXXXByValue()` everytime inside each enum. I want to write these methods inside the class and outside the enums, and access those methods with the help of class name.

I just want to declare my constants inside enum.

Please kindly suggest me an idea or a way so I can make this method universal which will work for each and every enum. I want to write these methods in such a way so it can be accessed for all enums enclosed in my class. I thought about generics but I have little knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics to push functionality up to a parent class by telling the parent class that the type is an `enum` that implements an interface.

```
// Use an interface to inform the super class what the enums can do.
public interface Named {
    public String getName();
}

// Super class of all Tables.
public static class Table<E extends Enum<E> & Named> {
    private final Class<E> itsClass;
    private final String sheetName;
    private final String fileName;

    public Table(Class<E> itsClass) {
        this.itsClass = itsClass;
        // Walk the enum to get filename and sheet name.
        String sheetName = null;
        String fileName = null;
        for ( E e: itsClass.getEnumConstants() ){
            if ( e.name().equals("FILENAME")) {
                fileName = e.getName();
            }
            if ( e.name().equals("THEAD")) {
                sheetName = e.getName();
            }
        }
        this.sheetName = sheetName;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    // Use the interface and the enum details to do your stuff.
    public E getByName (String name) {
        for ( E e: itsClass.getEnumConstants() ){
            if ( e.getName().equals(name)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// Extend Table and tell it about your enum using the super constructor.
public static class TableContent extends Table<TableContent.Nit> {

    public TableContent() {
        super(TableContent.Nit.class);
    }

    public enum Nit implements Named{
        FILENAME("Nit-workorder-list"),
        THEAD("NIT WORKORDER"),
        TENDERSPECNO("TENDER SPECFICATION NO."),
        FEE("TENDER FEE"),
        SDAMOUNT("SD AMOUNT"),
        TYPE("NIT TYPE"),
        PRE_BID("PRE BIDDING DATE"),
        OPEN_DATE("OPENING DATE"),
        STATUS("CONTRACTOR STATUS");

        private final String name;

        Nit(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , but what if i want to create multiple ENUM in TableContent class, you pass (TableContent.Nit.Class) in super, but i have ten enum to be included i the same class,

Comment: see my source code, you will find..   public enum NitWorkOrder {
      }
       public enum NitList {
      }   in the same class

Comment: @Zia Then perhaps pass a `List<Class<Enum>>` to the constructor but using one `enum` per class would clearly be easier to work with. The core concept here is to use `super(xxx.class)` and make the `enum` implement an interface that allows the superclass to get what it needs from the sub-class.

Comment: thank you so much, one more thing i want to fetch values corresponding to the enum constant but i am not able to use values() function.

Comment: @Zia - See my `Table` constructor - `itsClass.getEnumConstants()`.

Comment: public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Table t=new TableContent1();
        System.out.println("File Name"+" "+ t.getByName(TableContent1.Nit.FILENAME.getName()));
    }
}   Its not producing required output..instead of printing "Nit-workorder-list" it printing "FILENAME", am I doing some mistakes.????????????